# Oracle text indices on top of a materialized view

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a materialized view of a complex join, which I would like to have some of its columns be searcheable using Oracle Text.  I've already created the indicies on the underlying table.  Do you I have to create new indicies again for this materialized view?

thank you,

Joyce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if your queries reference  the materialized view.

Comment: +1: Answer is yes. Best to think of a materialized view as a new table - you need to index it as you would any other table